# Google Map API not loading after refreshing on random pc

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The google map loads well on my pc even if I refresh the page or hard refresh it but when some people access it, it won't load after they refresh the page where the map is located. I don't think this is a page on load issue because I already trapped that problem using this code

```
//---This condition traps google map API loading conflict with the page onload
if(isPageLoaded){
    //--Executes directly if page has already been loaded
    initializeMap($scope, $timeout, $cookies, $pageViewCtrl);
}else{
    //--If page was not yet loaded, Waits for the page to be ready, then initialize map
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function docStateChange(e) {

        if (e.target.readyState == 'complete') {
            e.target.removeEventListener('readystatechange', docStateChange);

            //console.log("Page is ready.");
            initializeMap($scope, $timeout, $cookies, $pageViewCtrl);

            isPageLoaded = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Inside Initialize map

```
function initializeMap($scope, $timeout, $cookies, $pageViewCtrl)
{
    var branchlong, branchlat;
    branchlong = $cookies.get(LONGITUDE);
    branchlat = $cookies.get(LATITUDE);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(branchlat),parseFloat(branchlong)),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false
        });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        // do something only the first time the map is loaded
        isMapInitialized = true;
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map.getStreetView(),'visible_changed',function(){
        //Street View listener codes here
    });
};
```

I made some observation. I let my other teammates access the page and refresh it. Some loads well, some doesn't. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it seems like the problem is on eventlistener `readystatechange`.
It's not firing on some browser.

What I did is I used an alternative which is an easier approach.
In my controller, I put the codes inside a `scope`

```
$scope.mapInitiator = function() {
  initializeMap($scope, $timeout, $cookies, $pageViewCtrl);
}
```

Then in my HTML

```
<div id="map" ng-init="mapInitiator()"></div>
```